# Data consolidation using Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, consolidation

We sell our product via a number of different retailers. These shops send us reports of what they have sold and we need to import this into our new stock management system as a master file.

The stores do not and will not provide the data in a uniform way based on our desired template.

I therefore need a way of consolidating ranges of data that without having a unique ID for each line, with minimal manual formatting from the data importer to help save time.

http://s14.postimg.org/arslbnnxt/excelconsolidation.jpg

As you can see in the 2 examples above, nothing is in the same order and some of the supplied fields haven't been used. The column headers are static, only the data is actually pasted.

I've tried using the Excel Data consolidation tool but the SUM function just wants to add everything up or simply reports a single value, I've played with Vlookup but I then need to dedicate a number of rows to each store which results in lots of empty rows.

If you can point me in the right direction I'm more than happy to research the tool or function I need, web searches keep bringing me back to the consolidation tool.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that column headers are static, you actually do have a unique ID.

The task can be accomplished by using `HLOOKUP` with Column headers as lookup value. 
However, the formula will depend on how you organize or store input sheets from different stores.

Here I have tested a setup where each store input is pasted in consecutive sheets starting from 'Sheet1'. i.e. Store1 in Sheet1, store2 in Sheet2 ... with row 1 containing header.

Then in consolidated sheet using helper columns for identifying sheet and row number, the formulas look like this

in A2    `=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(A$1,INDIRECT("Sheet"&$H2&"!A:O"),$I2,0),"")`

in H3   `=IFERROR(IF(INDIRECT("Sheet"&H2&"!A"&I2+1)="",H2+1,H2),"")`  (if no more records, increment sheet number)

in I3   `=IFERROR(IF((H3-H2)=0,I2+1,2),"")`  (if sheet number changed, reset row number to 2)

Initial value for H2 = 1 , I2 = 2

[image]

Test file: [Storefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Jnpce9U56zbU9zekhnTkhtTW8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is great PankajR Thank you - I wouldn't have gone anywhere this solution :)

Would you happen to have an excel source file you could upload to allow me to plan about and learn a little more please?

Comment: I've managed to get this working thanks to your instructions. However would there be anyway I could more appropriately name the sheets? Like with the name of the shop?

Comment: @Dinoshaw I have attached the test file with edited post above. I noticed there was wrong reference in formula for A2, now corrected. I think you already figured it out.

Comment: For naming sheets to make them identifiable, maybe you could use coding system for stores with consecutive numbers or use one more helper column to list out name of stores in sequence and use that list to increment to next sheet. I will test this and let you know.

Comment: @Dinoshaw  Try this version: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Jnpce9U56zTVNyLTdxUERCOVU/view?usp=sharing).  With a list of sheet names in column, I have used `INDEX-MATCH` to get next sheet name for reference in `HLOOKUP`. I haven't edited main post since that is good enough for general scenario.